# Rufus “Windows To Go” fails to boot and shows errors

Tags: windows, bootable-media, rufus

I made tiny11 installation on my Kingston 64GB USB flash drive.

It was working for few days, but now sometimes it fails to boot and when it boots running programs I'm getting missing DLL errors.

Is my USB flash drive failing?

It passes chkdsk with no errors, is there any software that can test it for read errors? Most of what I know of are for HDD and SSD.

Comment: Can you provide any specifics?

Comment: I'm looking for software that can scan usb flash drive for errors and tell me if Nand inside is dying or windows install on it got corrupted so i ca just format and reinstall.

Comment: We don’t do software recommendations here at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be physical drive issues, or just as likely, it could be issues in Tiny 11, or the way it was used (e.g., not shutting down properly). One common reason for failure is using the USB on a different device from that on which it was created. Each PC (even identical-seeming models) requires specific drivers, and not all drivers are included when making the portable Windows USB.

Tools like [Tiny 10](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/tiny10-iso-download-install.html), Tiny 11 and Hasleo's [WinToUSB](https://www.hasleo.com/), are interesting *experiments* (The Tiny releases are all *Beta*), but are not a panacea for creating a portable OS.